# Retornar valor de dentro de fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

Estou tentando ler um arquivo local em JavaScript e colocar seus dados em uma variável e até agora escrevi o seguinte código:

```
function fetchDictionary() {
    const URL_TO_FETCH = './lang-portuguese.txt';
    fetch(URL_TO_FETCH).then(res => res.text())
    .then(data => obj = data).then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
}

function buildWords() {   
    console.log(fetchDictionary())
}
```

E isso funciona corretamente, no console aparece o conteúdo do arquivo se eu chamo a `fetchDictionary()`.

Porém, se eu troco o `console.log(data)` por um `return data;` e tento chamar essa função `fetchDictionary()` na função `buildWords()`, ela só retorna um `undefined`.

Qual o erro que estou cometendo? Já li várias [documentações](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), [tutoriais](https://braziljs.org/blog/fetch-api-e-o-javascript/) e não consigo enxergar onde errei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acontece que o `fetch` retorna uma promessa e, sendo assim, você consegue utilizar o valor utilizando o `then` ou `await` e não diretamente:

```
function fetchDictionary() {
    const URL_TO_FETCH = './lang-portuguese.txt';
    return fetch(URL_TO_FETCH).then(res => res.text())
    .then(data => obj = data).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    })
}

function buildWords() {   
    fetchDictionary()then(console.log);
}
```